# delete and clear all items in combobox win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

I'm building a windows application, and I have this combobox refusing to get clean. I want the combo box items to be deleted between one button click to another. I tried :

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_LIST_COMMANDS, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
```

and also:

```
SendMessage(CommandsListBox, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
```

but none of them work. I  dont get 0 when I call LB_GETCOUNT after one of the above calls.

```
        case SOME_EVENT:

            ProfileHandler.IdentityIndex = (int)SendMessage(ProfilesCombo, 
CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(ProfilesCombo, CB_GETLBTEXT, 
(WPARAM)ProfileHandler.stringIndex, (LPARAM)ProfileHandler.string);
            if (ProfileHandler.IdentityIndex == -1) {
                MessageBox(hWnd, "Invalid !", "Error !", MB_OK);
                break;
            }

            StringsSet.clear();
            if (fuc.GetStrings(string(ProfileHandler.string), &StringsSet) 
== SERVER_ERROR) {
                MessageBox(hWnd, "Error Loading strings", "Error !", MB_OK);
                break;
            }

            SendMessage(CommandsListBox, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0); // reset 
content before writing strings
            it = StringsSet.begin();
            for (; it != StringsSet.end(); ++it)
            {
                    (int)SendMessage(CommandsListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0,
(LPARAM)(*it).c_str());
            }
            break;
```

so, I between every SOME_EVENT received by click, I want to clear the combobox, and load the string again.
right now what's happenning is that every time I click the button, and the SOME_EVENT event received, I just load the commands all over again, causing a duplication .
any idea how to solve this??

Comment: Is it a combo or a listbox? You need to make up your mind. **CB_xxx** messages are for combos, **LB_xxx** messages are for listboxes.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that, you solve it ! @JonathanPotter

Comment: Add it as answer so others can find a solution quicker if they search for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote code that resets all items into a ComboBox. The correct way is to use:
SendMessage(hcombobox, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
I write this because the problem was that the user that started this thread was using a ListView and not a ComboBox.
Jonathan Potter solved this issue.
I've written this to give visibility to the correct answer.
Forgive my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SendMessage(hChildWindows[1], CB_DELETESTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);`

This message will clear only one line in ComboBox (Item or String)